# Can I interact with other UDFs created using C# (ExcelDNA) through office-js plugin

Tags: office-js, excel-dna

I want to develop a sidepane plugin using office-js framework that will call some of the UDFs registered using another plugin I've created with Excel-DNA library. So far, reading the documentation, I haven't come across anything that talks about the possibility of interacting with other Addins from the office-js.

Is that possible?

For example, workflow could be:

1. User opens the side pane
2. User fills in the form
3. Office-JS makes a call to UDF registered by another addin created using ExcelDNA
4. UDF returns Array and shows in Excel

Answer (score 1):

This is not a supported scenario. The only way to interact with the workbook is through the data model APIs and calculation (Calc triggers UDF and it updates the range data and add-in reads the range data). Events API does help to get notified when things change.